# port forwarding in vagrant (bento/ubuntu-16.04) and localhost is not opening too

Tags: python, vagrant, webserver, crud, vagrantfile

I'm trying to make a web server in python using database with vagrant(bento/ubuntu-16.04).

vagrant is up with all ports forwarding.
then after executing `` python webserver.py```
but localhost is not opening.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' version '2.3.5' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
   default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
   default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
   default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
   default: 5000 (guest) => 5000 (host) (adapter 1)
   default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
   default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
```

then after 
`$ python webserver.py` 
shows "web server running on port 8080"

but localhost is not opening.
And showing this

`Safari cant open the page "localhost:8080/hello" because the server unexpected dropped the connection.`

Comment: run `netstat -tulpn` and post the output. Also check and make sure ubuntus firewall is off, or configured to allow port 8080

Comment: after running this ```$ netstat -tulpn
netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol ```
it shows this.

Comment: i run web server from terminal and opened another window  in vagrant shh and run this
 ```$ curl http://localhost:8080

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused```

what should i do , i got frustrated with it